# How to back these checkboxes by the datastore?

Tags: python, database, google-app-engine, jinja2

I want to save checkbox value to a db and use them in google appengine project. my previous question was about storing this to a session. I modified this simple google project by that. but cant get this work. It saves guestbook entries but not checkboxes.

here is html:

```
      <html>
  <body>
    {% for greeting in greetings %}
      {% if greeting.author %}
        <b>{{ greeting.author }}</b> wrote:
      {% else %}
        An anonymous person wrote:
      {% endif %}
      <blockquote>{{ greeting.content|escape }}</blockquote>
    {% endfor %}

    <form action="/sign" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" id="opt1" name="option 1" {% if not greetings.opts or "option 1" in greetings.opts %}checked="1"{% endif %} /><span class="font90" style="cursor:default;" >{{("Option 1")}} </span>
<input type="checkbox" id="opt2" name="option 2" {% if not greetings.opts or "option 2" in greetings.opts %}checked="1"{% endif %} /><span class="font90" style="cursor:default;" >{{("Option 2")}}</span>



      <div><textarea name="content" rows="3" cols="60"></textarea></div>
      <div><input type="submit" value="Sign Guestbook"></div>
    </form>

    <a href="{{ url }}">{{ url_linktext }}</a>
    <br>
    <br>



  <br>

  </body>
</html>
```

and helloword.py:

```
import urllib
import webapp2

from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.api import users

import jinja2
import os

jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)))


class Greeting(db.Model):
  """Models an individual Guestbook entry with an author, content, and date."""
  opts=db.StringListProperty()
  author = db.StringProperty()
  content = db.StringProperty(multiline=True, indexed=False)
  date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)



def _GuestbookKey(guestbook_name=None):
  """Constructs a Datastore key for a Guestbook entity with guestbook_name."""
  return db.Key.from_path('Guestbook', guestbook_name or 'default_guestbook')


class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

  def get(self):  # pylint:disable-msg=invalid-name
    """Handle GET requests."""
    guestbook_name = self.request.get('guestbook_name')
    greetings_query = Greeting.all().ancestor(
        _GuestbookKey(guestbook_name)).order('-date')
    greetings = greetings_query.fetch(10)

    if users.get_current_user():
      url = users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)
      url_linktext = 'Logout'
    else:
      url = users.create_login_url(self.request.uri)
      url_linktext = 'Login'
##    opt=self.request.get('opts',[])



    template_values = {
        'greetings': greetings,
        'url': url,
        'url_linktext': url_linktext,

    }
##    'opts': dict.fromkeys(opt, 'checked')

    template = jinja_environment.get_template('index.html')
    self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))


class Guestbook(webapp2.RequestHandler):

  def post(self):  # pylint:disable-msg=invalid-name
    """Handle POST requests."""
    # We set the same parent key on the 'Greeting' to ensure each greeting is in
    # the same entity group. Queries across the single entity group will be
    # consistent. However, the write rate to a single entity group should
    # be limited to ~1/second.

    guestbook_name = self.request.get('guestbook_name')
    greeting = Greeting(parent=_GuestbookKey(guestbook_name))

    if users.get_current_user():
      greeting.author = users.get_current_user().nickname()
    allopts=['option 1','option 2','option 3']
    greeting.opts=[op for op in allopts if self.request.get(op)]

##    greeting.opts=self.request.get("opts", allow_multiple=True)



    greeting.content = self.request.get('content')
    greeting.put()
    self.redirect('/?' + urllib.urlencode({'guestbook_name': guestbook_name}))


APP = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
    ('/sign', Guestbook),
], debug=True)
```

Comment: First, you're defining the `ops` property in model `Greeting` as a `db.ListProperty(db.Key)` -- **why**?  What at all does it have to do with `db.Key`s?  Then you're setting it to a list of strings instead.  I'm mildly surprised it doesn't crash at that point, but it's certainly not surprising it doesn't save things properly!  Next, in your template, you've put your checkboxes **outside** of the `form` -- **why**?  Whatever your mysterious reason, this of course means their values are not sent to the server when the form is submitted.  There's more, but this comment is out of space.

Comment: @AlexMartelli :) I put in the post form now, and changed listproperty to blobproperty. I guess the problem is at opt=self.request.get('ops',[])

Comment: Yes, that's indeed yet another bug (typo?): you're getting `"ops"` (in two different places), but in the template the `name` of your checkboxes is `"opts"` with an extra `t`, so, change the `get`.  Also a `BlobProperty` is **not** a list of strings, you're using the old deprecated `db` for a new application rather than the new recommended `ndb`, and you never use the `ops` property of greeting entities **at all** (you try to set it once, but then ignore it completely, you `get` stuff from the **request** even in the `get` method).  I'm sure there's more, but these are already FAR too many bugs

Comment: @AlexMartelli I have changed a little bit. Could you check again please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite all of its remaining defects this code after the edits does save a list of checked checkboxes -- it never **shows** them because in the template it checks `greetings.opts`, which does not exist, instead of checking `greeting.opts` (no `s` just before the `.`) **inside** the loop where `greeting`, singular, is defined.

So e.g changing the heart of the template to

```
    {% for greeting in greetings %}
      {% if greeting.author %}
        <b>{{ greeting.author }}</b> wrote:
      {% else %}
        An anonymous person wrote:
      {% endif %}
      <blockquote>{{ greeting.content|escape }}</blockquote>
<input type="checkbox" name="option 1" {% if not greeting.opts or "option 1" in greeting.opts %}checked="1"{% endif %} /><span class="font90" style="cursor:default;" >{{("Option 1")}} </span>
<input type="checkbox" name="option 2" {% if not greeting.opts or "option 2" in greeting.opts %}checked="1"{% endif %} /><span class="font90" style="cursor:default;" >{{("Option 2")}}</span>
      <p><p>
    {% endfor %}

    <p><p>
    <form action="/sign" method="post">
```

will display right after each greeting two checkboxes set or unset depending on how they were when the form for that greeting was submitted.

There are many small remaining issues (e.g strictly speaking it's wrong HTML to have `checked=1`, but browsers typically ignore those mistakes), of which the worst one is using ancient `db` rather than nice new `ndb`.

But, this change in the template (plus all the bugs I had previously mentioned in my comments and your edits have now fixed) does seem to answer the question as it stands.

Comment: thanks but it is not working as I want. how can I make this save only two options not for all greeting

Comment: @St3114, you make a different entity keyed by whatever you like -- say the current user's name -- and have the `opts` there; your choice to save the `opts` with each greeting was one of the many weird design choices I meant as "many small remaining issues".  Time for yet another Q?  (And BTW you're gaining rep, enough to upvote now, you know!-)

Comment: i was going to sleep, i'll try tomorrow

Comment: I wrote that inputs outside of for loop but it is not saving checkboxes, it always comes with checked. here I deployed http://dontklark.appspot.com/

Comment: @St3114, outside the loop (and in the form) you're checking `if not greetings.opts`.  That doesn't exists (`greetings` is a list thus it has no `opts` attribute) so the `if` is satisfied and you always show those checkbox as checked.  Then you save them fine and never **use** the values you've saved: as I've shown in the **additions** to the template they're saved fine with each greeting.  If you've **removed** them from the form then you've resurrected that bug, put them in **both** places.  The ones in the form start checked & get saved, the others just display.

Comment: I have changed it to this https://app.box.com/s/kirnk0gvpslmo57oeelh7yd44amnv0mm it seems to work on localhost but when I try to deploy it gives urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 8] _ssl.c:510: EOF occurred in violation of protocol>
 even if I commented out urllib

Comment: I think there might be a problem with google and its services

Comment: @St3114, I don't think that's the case -- in any case, the issue has nothing to do with checkboxes nor with the datastore any more, rather it appears tied to that `redirect` to a mysterious `/?saved` URL which your main page doesn't know how to handle (it does seem an invalid URL, try e.g `/?saved=yes` to make it syntactically valie). Simplify the code and post a separate Q about redirect problems if they persist.

Comment: it does give the same error when I try to deploy default google guestbook app I hope it is temprorary

Comment: Likely last comment on this Q as Stackoverflow starts scolding about "extended discussions in comments" -- **open a new more specific Q**, likely my last chance to tell you!  I just did git clone https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-guestbook-python.git , edited app.yaml to an app of mine, used appcfg.update to deploy; waited a couple minutes for index to build; works perfectly.  **open a new Q**, already!, showing **exactly** what you did and what problems you observe!!!